# Is it correct to use un-tinted or non-tinted in this use?

Tags: prefixes, negative-prefixes

> Related forms
>
> nontinted, adjective
>
> overtint, verb
>
> overtint, noun
>
> retint, verb (used with object)
>
> untinted, adjective

Source: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/untinted?s=t

> One un- is added to verbs to indicate the reversal of an action:
>
> Non- is added to nouns that imply some “action, condition, or quality.” The addition of “non-” has the sense of “absence or lack of”: Ex. non-standard.

Source: http://bottomlineenglish.com/when-to-use-the-negative-prefixes-un-and-non

---

**Question:**

In the following would un-tinted or non-tinted be the correct use, and preferably an explanation why. It seems like non-tinted is the better description based on the BottomEnglish explanation but I'm not sure. Un- seems to imply the act of removing a tint, Non- just means lacking a tint. To me it's easy to think "That window was just un-tinted by the mechanic." While "The car for sale has non-tinted windows."

> While on non-tinted windows the sticker is barely visible.
>
> While on un-tinted windows the sticker is barely visible.

Am I correct understanding that non-tinted is the better use in this sentence?

Comment: Why not *clear*?

Answer (score 1):

So, first off, you're looking for the adjective versions, so the quote about 'un for verbs' would be better replaced by the section from the same source on 'un for adjectives':

```
The other un- is added to adjectives to indicate the opposite of the positive form of the adjective.
```

And one of the examples it gives is dyed/undyed, a very similar concept to tinting.  From my own experience, I've heard untinted, but not nontinted, and Google's ngrams seem to indicate a [similar picture](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nontinted%2Cuntinted%2Cnon-tinted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnontinted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuntinted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnon%20-%20tinted%3B%2Cc0):
[image: NGram Chart]

Comment: His confusion may be based on the fact that this is a past-tense verb being used as an adjective. I'm not sure English is consistent about whether to apply verb or adjective rules in such cases.

Answer (score -1):

"non-" implies the absence of a given condition.

"un-" implies the reversal or removal of a given existing condition.

Applying this concept to gasoline, we see that "UNleaded" gasoline is a complete misnomer, since gasoline IS NATURALLY nonleaded and that only a fool would take leaded gasoline, remove the lead and then call it UNleaded gasoline.